# how to remove the floating button from navigation drawer?

Tags: android

how to remove the floating button from navigation drawer in android studio?
is it safe to remove this code from the main activity?

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
 .setAction("Action", null).show();
 }
 });
```

Comment: For first, indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally safe to remove the floating action button.

- First remove the FAB from the xml file
- And then remove FAB from the activity code.

Comment: I find it easier to remove it in the xml first so you exactly know where you referenced the view in your code

Comment: @Denny , yes Android studio shows error in java code when you delete in xml so it is easier to debug.